# controller action called twice on using curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I have a strange issue. 
Inside a laravel controller action I am initiating a curl call to an API on the same server and my same controller function (in which the curl call is initiated) is called again after the curl call is finished.

```
    $postdata = http_build_query($postvars);

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . $hostname . ':8083/api/');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    $answer = curl_exec($curl);
```

The controller action is a post action in which I am making a curl post to an API on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the right way to call a method on controller.
Let's say you have

```
public function test(){

}
```

and

```
public function test2(){

}
```

you want to call test2 from test you can do it like this:

```
public function test(){
   $this->test2();
}
```

Comment: sorry ? I didnt add any controller function in my question. This curl call is made inside the helper

Comment: you said `Inside a laravel controller action I am initiating a curl call to an API on the same server and my same controller function` . Anyway, if you want to call controller method, it's not best practice to use Curl for that. Register named route in your web.php and call a route.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I guess I failed to explain to exact scenario, I have a controller action A called on a form post, in that controller action there is a helper function, which makes a cURL call to an API on the same server outside laravel (running on different port 8083), so when this cURL call is initiated my same controller action A is called again for no reason. Hope I was able to explain the exact scenario.

Comment: @AsimShaikh yeah I get it now. Well it should't be called by default, so I guess your code for a function you are calling is not right. So look into that. Also don't use curl for that (i mean not directly). Try using guzzle

Comment: I am facing the same issue even after using guzzle :(